# Wordpress Error log location

Tags: php, wordpress, apache

Where is the default error log file of wordpress. I am getting 500 error and wanted to see the error. I am getting 500 internal server errror

Comment: Check your error logs?

Comment: By default, /var/log/apache2/error.log

Comment: hmmm. Its not comming up there?

Comment: What is your system's setup? Is it with vhost configuration or is it managed by a cPanel?

Comment: it is  vhost. not cpanel

Answer (score 3):

You can specify the location of your error log inside your vhost:

```
ErrorLog /path/to/error/log/error.log
```

Then restart your apache, and you should see the errors in your log.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case if you don't want to look into error log file every time

**PHP.ini way:**

```
error_reporting = E_ALL
display_errors = On
```

Same thing can be done from **PHP fil**e as well, see below:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```